# Docker and MariaDB issue: "Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mariadb/mariadb.sock'"

Tags: linux, docker, mariadb

I want to containerize, on a Debian 11 VM, a web application implemented in Python and the database MariaDB which the app uses.

The application works well on a docker container, but it isn't the same for the MariaDB server, which i need on another container.

When i try to access with root and password (command "mariadb -p"), i get the error message:
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mariadb/mariadb.sock' (2)`

If i try to start the server with `service mariadb start` i get:

```
* Starting MariaDB database server mariadb                                [fail]
```

I tried to use different images but only the linuxserver/mariadb works (which is with alpine), but i need a docker container that works on ubuntu or debian.

The command i used for run the images (with latest version) was:

```
 docker run -it -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_password -d --name mariadb-server mariadb-image /bin/bash
```

Maybe i should uninstall MariaDB on VM before the configuration on Docker container (?). I stopped the service on VM but it wasn't enough.

Someone know how to solve it?

EDIT (SOLVED):
"You have a command override /bin/bash at the end of your docker run command; that command runs instead of the normal container process. That is, you're getting an interactive shell and not a database server. You should rarely if ever need a shell in a container. Does just deleting that /bin/bash command help?". This comment helps me to solve the issue. Without /bin/bash parameter MariaDB works perfectly. For verify it you have just to use the command `docker exec -it mariadb-container /bin/bash` to go into the container and then tring the same command `mariadb -p`.

Comment: You have a command override `/bin/bash` at the end of your `docker run` command; that command runs _instead of_ the normal container process.  That is, you're getting an interactive shell and not a database server.  You should rarely if ever need a shell in a container.  Does just deleting that `/bin/bash` command help?  The error message also suggests you might not have correctly configured your application to talk to the database; what does that configuration look like, and is the application also running in a container and if so how?

Comment: Containers require a Kernel and the distro container can quite legitimately be different from the host OS container and it will just work. To connect `mariadb` from outside the container to the container requires `--protocol tcp --host {containerIP} --port 3306`.